# how to fix hard drive errors?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

Suddenly, My hard disk is not working. While booting, It gives `failed command: READ DMA` and `status: { DRDY }` error. So, I booted the system with live CD and tried to mount the hard disk. It gives the following error.

**kern.log**

```
Jan 29 18:58:43 mint kernel: [  353.763226] usb 1-5: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5
Jan 29 18:58:44 mint kernel: [  353.895886] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2338
Jan 29 18:58:44 mint kernel: [  353.895893] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
Jan 29 18:58:44 mint kernel: [  353.895899] usb 1-5: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge
Jan 29 18:58:44 mint kernel: [  353.895903] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: JMicron
Jan 29 18:58:44 mint kernel: [  353.895907] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 000000000000
Jan 29 18:58:44 mint kernel: [  353.896072] usb 1-5: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Jan 29 18:58:44 mint kernel: [  353.896832] scsi5 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Jan 29 18:58:44 mint kernel: [  353.897123] usb-storage: device found at 5
Jan 29 18:58:44 mint kernel: [  353.897127] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
Jan 29 18:58:49 mint kernel: [  358.887333] usb-storage: device scan complete
Jan 29 18:58:49 mint kernel: [  358.887831] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ST332041 8AS                   PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
Jan 29 18:58:49 mint kernel: [  358.889424] scsi 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Jan 29 18:58:49 mint kernel: [  359.084346] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] 625142448 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
Jan 29 18:58:49 mint kernel: [  359.085076] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Jan 29 18:58:49 mint kernel: [  359.085082] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
Jan 29 18:58:49 mint kernel: [  359.085086] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jan 29 18:58:49 mint kernel: [  359.086570] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  359.086577]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 <
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.246559] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.246566] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.246573] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.246581] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.246588] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 02 8f ba f0 00 00 08 00
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.246604] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 42973936
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.246612] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 5371742
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.375718] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.375725] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.375731] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.375739] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.375746] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 02 8f ba f0 00 00 08 00
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.375762] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 42973936
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.375769] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 5371742
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.375794]  > sda4
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.483644] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.483650] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.483656] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.483663] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.483670] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 02 54 29 80 00 00 08 00
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.483685] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 39070080
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.483691] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 4883760
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.608301] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.608306] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.608312] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.608319] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.608326] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 02 54 29 80 00 00 08 00
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.608341] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 39070080
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.608347] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 4883760
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.741338] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.741345] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.741352] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.741359] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.741367] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.741382] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.741390] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.742223] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.742233] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.874351] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.874358] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.874365] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.874373] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.874380] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.874395] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.874403] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.998881] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.998888] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.998895] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.998903] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.998910] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.998925] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  383.998933] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  384.123538] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  384.123544] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  384.123550] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  384.123557] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  384.123564] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
Jan 29 18:59:14 mint kernel: [  384.123579] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
```

Is there any way to fix these errors?

Atleast, How to recover the data from the hard drive? Because, I have more important data in that hard disk.

What does these error means?

Comment: From your backups would be easiest.

Comment: @lain, Unfortunately I don't have any backup.

Comment: Now you know why not having backups of data you care about is a bad idea. If this is the same disk you've been having problems with since June last year then I've got absolutely no sympathy for you.

Comment: Not the same hard drive.

Comment: @sat: It really doesn't matter if it's the same hard drive or not. You've had hard drive issues before and you haven't taken steps to protect yourself - you're an amateur.

Answer (score 13):

Looking at your question history ([here](https://serverfault.com/questions/517486/error-while-mounting-partition-with-live-cd) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/516889/file-system-is-going-into-read-only-mode-frequently)), I do wonder if this is the same drive that's been causing you problems for *6 months*...

If that's the case, you've had ample warning and good advice on how to deal with the failing disk. At the very least, backups of some sort should have been in the plan.

At this point, a professional data recovery service may be the best option. It seems like it was a slow failure, so perhaps a mechanical issue. Some data recovery services will replace the drive controllers, arms, bearing, etc. or even transfer the platters to a new mechanism in order to do their best at recovering the remaining data from the disk.

Get an estimate. If the data is really valuable, you'll be able to attach a price to it.

Comment: Not the same hard drive. But, I remembered one thing that after the abnormal power fluctuation, this hard drive is not working. That time, My SMPS got failed. After I replaced the SMPS, then I came to know that there is problem with hard drive.

Answer (score 5):

Errors like these:

```
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.608312] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
Jan 29 18:59:13 mint kernel: [  383.608319] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
```

usually imply that your drive is fried, the quickest solution would be to replace the drive and restore from a backup.

if the live CD cant read/mount the disk then there likely is no simple/quick way to recover data off the disk. so without backups you probably are screwed i'm sorry to say.

specialist data recovery tools/services might get some data off the disk but i would caution you that the recovered data is often not in a useful format and takes many further hours of careful browsing to find your actual critical files from the disk and even then there are usually no guarentees that you will recover the required data - its also worth noting that you can potentially damage your disk further by going through such processes which might make it harder/impossible to recover any data

Rule #1 - always have some level of backups (even if its just dropbox for critical documents!)